# Mellin trasform $\text{csch}^3(x)$

Tags: calculus

Could you show the following integral ?:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s - 1}\operatorname{csch}^{3}\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x =
2^{-s}\left[\left(2^{s} - 4\right)\zeta\left(s - 2\right) -
\left(2^{s} - 1\right)\zeta\left(s\right)\right]\Gamma\left(s\right)$$

Comment: Come on antonio, the answer to all your question is the same : you need to study first a complex analysis course. And asking a question without looking at the answer not acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is my attempt, I don't know what it will be but in any case it will be, in my opinion, a great starting point.

First of all

$$\text{cosech}(x) = \frac{2}{e^x - e^{-x}}$$

Hence

$$\int_0^{+\infty} x^{s-1}\ \left(\frac{2}{e^x - e^{-x}}\right)^3\ \text{d}x$$

Arranging a bit to get

$$8\int_0^{+\infty}x^{s-1} \frac{(e^x)^3}{(e^{2z}-1)^3}\ \text{d}x =8\int_0^{+\infty}x^{s-1} \frac{e^{3x}}{(e^{2x}(1 - e^{-2x})^3} = 8\int_0^{+\infty}x^{s-1} \frac{e^{3x}}{e^{6x}(1 - e^{-2x})^3}\ \text{d}x$$

Now we can use the Geometric Series:

$$\frac{1}{(1 - e^{-2z})^3} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k = 2}^{+\infty} k(k-1)(e^{-2x})^{k-2}$$

to get

$$8\int_0^{+\infty}x^{s-1} e^{-3x} \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k = 2}^{+\infty} k(k-1)(e^{-2x})^{k-2} = 4\sum_{k = 2}^{+\infty} k(k-1)\int_0^{+\infty}x^{s-1} e^{-3x} (e^{-2x})^{k-2}\ \text{d}x $$

So

$$4\sum_{k = 2}^{+\infty} k(k-1)\int_0^{+\infty}x^{s-1} e^{-3x} e^{-2x(k-2)}\ \text{d}x = 4\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} k(k-1)\int_0^{+\infty}x^{s-1} e^{-x(2k-1)}\ \text{d}x$$

Now this is a well known integral: it's indeed:

$$\int_0^{+\infty}x^{s-1} e^{-x(2k-1)}\ \text{d}x = (2k-1)^{-s}\Gamma(s)$$

Indeed the two necessary conditions are satisfied:

$$\Re(s) >0 ~~~~~~~ \Re(k) > \frac{1}{2}$$

Finally we end up with a series:

$$4\sum_{k = 2}^{+\infty} k(k-1)(2k-1)^{-s}\Gamma(s) = 4\Gamma(s) \sum_{k = 2}^{+\infty} k(k-1)(2k-1)^{-s}$$

The series

$$\boxed{\sum_{k = 2}^{+\infty} k(k-1)(2k-1)^{-s}}$$

is **where I do stop** for the moment, because I need to check if what I did makes sense, and I need to find a sum for that...

**Possible details, later**

**FINAL EDIT, THANKS TO USER1952009 (you can see his comment below!)**

The series can start from $k = 1$, since the very first term will be zero.

Then, using a cute trick: write the part

$$4k(k-1) = 4k^2 - 4k$$

as

$$(2k-1)^2 - 1$$

To get

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty}\left((2k-1)^2 - 1\right)(2k-1)^{-s}$$

Splitting the sum into two pieces, we recognise the Riemann Zeta:

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} (2k-1)^{2-s} = 2^{2-s} \left(2^{s-2}-1\right) \zeta (s-2)$$

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} (2k-1)^{-s} = 2^{-s} \left(2^s-1\right) \zeta (s)$$

Putting together:

$$2^{2-s} \left(2^{s-2}-1\right) \zeta (s-2) - 2^{-s} \left(2^s-1\right) \zeta (s) = $$

This can be transformed, with simple algebra into

$$2^{-s}\left((2^2 - 4)\zeta(s-2) - (2^s-1)\zeta(s)\right)$$

Without forgetting the Gamma term we left apart, we end up with your desired result:

$$\boxed{2^{-s}\left((2^2 - 4)\zeta(s-2) - (2^s-1)\zeta(s)\right)\Gamma(s)}$$

Comment: well done it seem very near

Comment: @antonioasis Thank you! I'm checking if I did right until when I arrived, to go on :D

Comment: Looks really good so far! I anticipate the finale!

Comment: @antonioasis Ok, so far what I did is correct. Now.. that series... xD

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Many thanks Sir! I'm having to deal with that series now!

Comment: @antonioasis I added some details! Yet, two terms are still to be calculated. But I'm trying!

Comment: @FourierTransform "+ terms" XD your commentary on this is fantastic. It's like reading the script of the most mathematical comedy ever made. Bravo XD

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Haha! Thanks xD I hope this comedy will have a really happy ending!

Comment: once you have $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(k-1)(2k-1)^{-s}$, write that $4 k(k-1) = (2k-1)^2 - 1 $, and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (2k-1)^{-s} = \zeta(s)(1-2^{-s})$ so that $4\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(k-1)(2k-1)^{-s} = \zeta(s-2)(1-2^{-s+2})-\zeta(s)(1-2^{-s})$ for $Re(s) > 3$ $\qquad$ (using that $2^{-s} \zeta(s) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (2k)^{-s}$ you have $(1-2^{-s}) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (2k-1)^{-s})$

Comment: @user1952009 Your trick was as simple as amazing! Thank you very much, I edited and quoted you. Thanks!!!

Comment: @antonioasis DONE! :D

Comment: +1. Nice proof. I was trying to do some contour integral but I left it. The residues calculation is quite cumbersome which also has to take care of the $z^{s - 1}$ branch-cut. Your proof is 'quite clean'.

Comment: @FelixMarin Thank you! I would love to see a contour integration solution though! If you have some ideas, post them!! That was actually the first method I thought about when I saw the hyperbolic cosecant (via exp).

Comment: The contour integral yields sums like $\sum_{n}\left\vert n\right\vert^{s - 1}$ and $\sum_{n}\left\vert n\right\vert^{s - 3}$ which is usual in this type of hyperbolic-like integrals. Maybe, you can introduce some 'convergent term' likes $\exp\left(-\epsilon\left\vert n\right\vert\right)$ but it will produce a "comments war" ( LOL !!! ).